# Why my cookie not showing up on linked page?

Tags: php, cookies, mamp

very simple question.

This is my index.php:

```
<?php
setcookie("testcookie", "i am value of cookie", 86400, '/');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="newpage.php">go to next</a>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my newpage.php:

```
<?php
echo "ok ok ";
echo $_COOKIE["testcookie"];
?>
```

My second page echoes "ok ok " but it doesn't echo the cookie.
I checked network, the index.php has the cookie "testcookie" but newpage.php doesn't have access to it if I click the link.

I'm using MAMP.

Comment: check if it is set and then reload it "once it's been assigned a value". Cookies only take effect "after" it's been set, you didn't do that.

Comment: Where do you save any value to the cookie?

Comment: Read the docs http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: @xander woops, sorry edited to full code, copy and pasted wrongly.

Comment: oh so now my comments are worthless. Nonetheless, you should still check if the cookie is set/not empty and check for errors.

Comment: @Fred-ii- , I have 1 week of experience on PHP. I have gone back to index.php reloaded. Go to newpage and reloaded. Also checked network for the cookie, but no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`86400` is a long, long time ago in the past.

Your cookie expires immediately.

See the [documentation](http://php.net/setcookie):

> The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number of seconds since the epoch. In other words, you'll most likely set this with the time() function plus the number of seconds before you want it to expire. Or you might use mktime(). time()+60*60*24*30 will set the cookie to expire in 30 days. If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).

Comment: changed it to mktime(). time()+60*60*24*30 but still cookie not showing up (also refresh etc.).

Comment: With your code your might want to use `time()+86400`!?

Comment: Depending on your browser you can also look for the cookie file in your browser cache :)